# Clean st.cache for specific function in Steamlit

Tags: python, decorator, streamlit

In streamlit, how can I just clean specific `st.cache` functions for a part.

I have the following structure:

```py
@st.cache
def get_data_from_csv(folder_name, csv_name):
    # loop through all csv files under that folder_name with name csv_name
    name_list = os.list_dir(folder_path)
    res = pd.DataFrame()
    for n in name_list:
        temp_df = pd.read_csv(name_list + csv_name)
        res = pd.concat([res, temp_df], axis=1, ignore_index = True)
    return res

@st.cache
def other_st_cache_function():
   pass

selected = st.sidebar.radio("some name", ["a", "b", "c"])
if selected == "a":
    df = get_data_from_csv("my_folder", "data.csv")
    st.dataframe(df)
elif selected == "b":
    df = other_st_cache_function()
    st.dataframe(df)
```

Let's assume after I selected "a", the `get_data_from_csv` function runs and shows my dataframe. Then the underlying data in "my_folder" changed, and I want to clean only the cached info in `get_data_from_csv` but not that in `other_st_cache_function`.

How do I do that?

Comment: Here is a discussion forum that might help you with the problem https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/how-can-i-clear-a-specific-cache-only/1963/3

Answer (score 0):

Streamlit doesn't natively support clearing only specific data from the cache, but you can use [session state](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/session-state) to similarly store and clear specific pieces of data, e.g.

```
# Delete a single key-value pair
del st.session_state[key]

# Delete all the items in Session state
for key in st.session_state.keys():
    del st.session_state[key]
```

Answer (score 0):

With further development made within the Streamlit library, this is now possible where it previously wasn't. For the sake of future netizens:

Streamlit offers different caching functions for different purposes. Read the documentation re: [caching](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/caching).

`st.cache_data` and `st.cache_resource` are provided to handle different cases. Roughly, use `st.cache_data` to hold data, where the the caching function returns a copy of that data. Use `st.cache_resource` for other things like ML models and database connections to be shared across sessions without duplication.

Each caching function provides the option to clear out its cache entirely or for a single function it decorates.

Clear out the whole cache:
`st.cache_data.clear()` or `st.cache_resource.clear()`

Clear our the cache for a specific function:

```py
@st.cache_data
def get_data():
    return [1,2,3]

data = get_data()

get_data.clear()
```

Further documentation for [`st.cache_data`](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/performance/st.cache_data) and [`st.cache_resource`](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/performance/st.cache_resource)